# Link sockets to an established Wi-Fi connection. Client socket connect times out

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have set up WPA protected Wi-Fi access point on one Raspberry Pi ("server") and successfully connected to that access point with other Raspberry Pi ("client").
Now, I need to send some data from client to server. I thought that creating a socket on the client side and connecting it to the (ip, port) on the server side would be possible, but self.connect(ip, port) always times out.

My client code is fairly simple:

```
def connect_as_client(self, host_address, target_port):
    try:
        self.client_socket.connect((host_address, target_port))
    except socket.error:
        # In case an error occurs, report it
        self._set_error_flag("CONNECTION_FAILURE")
        return False
    # Turn off blocking mode for new socket
    self.client_socket.setblocking(0)
    # Send Username and its length to the host
    self._send(self.client_socket, self.username)
    return True
```

If there is any other way to send data over established connection that does not include sockets, I am thankful for all suggestions.
Access point set up by following this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point

Comment: The problem description is implausible; `connect` doesn't return _Broken pipe_, `send` does.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. What happens is when I attempt to connect, my socket.connect request timeouts. And then I am trying to send through not-connected socket which causes Broken Pipe error. I will correct my question immediately.

Comment: Can we have a look at the output of `netstat -tnlp` on the _server_?

Comment: [tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:2236      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      4758/python3]....       
[tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:domain  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      5960/dnsmasq]...        
[tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:ssh        0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      245/sshd]...            
[tcp    0  0 localhost:ipp    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      895/cupsd]...           
[tcp6  0  0 [::]:domain        [::]:*        LISTEN      478/dnsmasq]...        
[tcp6  0  0 [::]:ssh              [::]:*        LISTEN      335/sshd]...          
[tcp6  0  0 localhost:ipp     [::]:*       LISTEN      489/cupsd]...

THE FIRST LINE IS SOCKET I HAVE OPENED.

Comment: Which `target_port` is used?

Comment: I have used 4758.

Comment: 4758 is the process ID of the server; the port number is the _2236_. But this cannot be the only issue, because I realize now that if the client could reach the server host and vice versa, though with a wrong port, a _connection refused_ should immediately be reported rather than a timeout. - Can you `ping` the `host_address` from the client host?

Comment: No, actually I cannot. I tried to and client didn't receive anything.

Comment: Perhaps better than me making individual suggestions, could you see if [What to check if 'pinging' doesn't work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/18506/what-to-check-if-pinging-doesnt-work) leads to progress?